# PHP: How to make a green area (background) in an image transparent?

Tags: php, image, background, transparent

I'm new here on Stackoverflow.

I would very much like figure out if it's possible to make a specific color of an image transparent using a PHP script. And if it is, how to go about doing it.

Let's say this is the image of which the background color (green) has to be completely transparent: [French Hotdog w/ green background](http://clubace.dk/hotdog1.jpg)

[image]

I've got absolutely no idea what a script like this would look like or even where to begin.
I imagine that you'd propably have to set the unwanted RGB color and then "scan" every single pixel in image to determine which pixels have to be transparent. But other than that I'm clueless.

Seriously hope someone here is able to help me out on this one.

Comment: Hi @Ace, this site is about concrete programming questions. You write you have no clue to begin. Then do your homework first and find at least one clue, e.g. the color (hint). Then start to write the code and then highlight where you hit the roadblock.

Answer (score 3):

> - **demo** : http://so.devilmaycode.it/php-how-to-make-a-green-area-background-in-an-image-transparent

first of all the image should be **png** cause **jpeg** don't support transparency then the code is like this:

```
<?php
   $image = 'test.png';
   $im = imagecreatefrompng($image); 
   //if you exactly know the RGB color indexes
   //$rgb = imagecolorexact($im, 0, 0, 0);
   //or keep the rgb color by position so at top 0 left 0
   $rgb = imagecolorat($im, 0, 0);
   imagecolortransparent($im, $rgb);
   header("Content-type: image/png");
   //display the image directly
   imagepng($im);
   // or save it
   // imagepng($im, 'test-to-transparent.png');
   imagedestroy($im); 
?>
```

Comment: Brilliant aSeptik!! :) And thank you for the comments in the script - really helpfull. Now I'm just thinking if there's a way to make every single green pixel in the image transparent, no matter the shade, hue, saturation or brightness of the color. This seeming to the only way to completely "remove" the background color. Any thoughts on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

[imagecolortransparent()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php) will help you:

```
...
$yourColor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($im, $yourColor);
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Narek, that makes perfect sence. However I'm afraid I'm gonna need some help to get the pixels of the image scaned for $yourColor.