# php imagecolortransparent is not working

Tags: php, gd

Attached is a simple PNG with pink corners of rgb 255 0 255.

I am pulling my hair out for 3 days now, why the heck such simple script won't turn these pink corners into transparents??

```
$note_src_im = imagecreatefrompng('testpink.png');

imagealphablending($note_src_im, FALSE);
imagesavealpha($note_src_im, TRUE);

$pink = imagecolorallocate($note_src_im, 255, 0, 255);
imagecolortransparent($note_src_im, $pink);

imagepng($note_src_im, '/testpinkresult.png');
```

Your help to fix these will be of a gold or platinum bar value at this point...

This is PHP 7 with newest GD.

[pink corners png image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvojE.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to make a green area (background) in an image transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852267/php-how-to-make-a-green-area-background-in-an-image-transparent)

Comment: Comment out your line of `imagesavealpha` and it should begin to work. - Not really a duplicate because he's already doing that to some extent. The addition of the extra line (not mentioned in the duplicate thread) is the cause of the trouble.

Comment: Nope, already tried every possible combination of imagesavealpha and imagealphablending TRUE/FALSE and not providing it at all.

Makes me wonder if there is something weird going on with the PNG file itself.

Comment: Well, I copy/pasted your code to my test server... and began to fiddle. Once I commented that one line, it began to output with clear corners. So... if thats not working for you, bugger... I have no clue then sorry.

Comment: However what I found interesting... is if I saved the changed image (from browser), it saved with pink corners (if I open with photoshop)... But in the browser it had transparent corners. I suspect theres a goofy issue there somewhere.

Comment: Yes Sorry I should mention.. dumping to browser makes corners transparent. Dropping into file via imagepng keeps them pink.
My PHP Version is 7.0.24 with DG bundled (2.1.0 compatible) 2.4.11 lib 30411. I think there may be bug in PHP/GD